# SWT and JFace in stand-alone mode tutorial recommendation

Tags: java, swt, jface

could you recommend me some good one tutorial about using SWT and JFace in stand-alone mode.

Comment: What do you mean by **stand-alone** mode? Are you referring to a non-plugin environment ??

Comment: I'm refering to mode where's no reference to Eclipse project is requried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly a tutorial, but the best documentation I know of for both SWT and JFace are the snippets:

[SWT snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)

[JFace snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets)

Reading (and trying) a snippet shows you how to implement one basic use case in a very clear way.

If you really crave for a tutorial, you might want to try this one: [Part1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui1/) [Part2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecgui2/) [Part3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui3/)

It's a bit old though, and some of the described paradigms have changed, e.g. the Viewers. See the snippets for the currently recommended way of implementing Viewers.